# Is it necessary to submit spark application jar?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, datastax

As stated in title I'm wondering if is it necessary to spark-submit *.jar?

I'm using Datastax Enterprise Cassandra for a while, but now I need to use Spark too. I watched almost all videos from [DS320: DataStax Enterprise Analytics with Apache Spark](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/getting-started-apache-spark) and there is nothing about connecting to spark remotely from java application.

Now I have 3 running nodes of DSE. I can connect to Spark from spark shell. But after 2 days of trying to connect to Spark from java code I'm giving up.

This is my Java code

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
sparkConf.setAppName("AppName");
//sparkConf.set("spark.shuffle.blockTransferService", "nio");
//sparkConf.set("spark.driver.host", "*.*.*.*");
//sparkConf.set("spark.driver.port", "7007");
sparkConf.setMaster("spark://*.*.*.*:7077");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
```

Result of connecting

```
16/01/18 14:32:43 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 2 requests outstanding when connection from *.*.*.*/*.*.*.*:7077 is closed
16/01/18 14:32:43 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master *.*.*.*:7077
java.io.IOException: Connection from *.*.*.*/*.*.*.*:7077 closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/01/18 14:33:03 ERROR TransportResponseHandler: Still have 2 requests outstanding when connection from *.*.*.*/*.*.*.*:7077 is closed
16/01/18 14:33:03 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master *.*.*.*:7077
java.io.IOException: Connection from *.*.*.*/*.*.*.*:7077 closed
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportResponseHandler.java:124)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelUnregistered(TransportChannelHandler.java:94)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:158)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:144)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:739)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:659)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/01/18 14:33:23 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
16/01/18 14:33:23 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
16/01/18 14:33:23 WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Drop UnregisterApplication(null) because has not yet connected to master
16/01/18 14:33:23 ERROR MapOutputTrackerMaster: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:208)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.sendTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster.stop(MapOutputTracker.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$12.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1756)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1229)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1755)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.dead(SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint.markDead(AppClient.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AppClient.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2.run(AppClient.scala:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/01/18 14:33:23 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread appclient-registration-retry-thread
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Error communicating with MapOutputTracker
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.sendTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTrackerMaster.stop(MapOutputTracker.scala:462)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$12.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1756)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1229)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1755)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.dead(SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint.markDead(AppClient.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AppClient.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2.run(AppClient.scala:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1326)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:208)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker.askTracker(MapOutputTracker.scala:110)
    ... 18 more
16/01/18 14:33:23 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[appclient-registration-retry-thread,5,main]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.error(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.dead(SparkDeploySchedulerBackend.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint.markDead(AppClient.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AppClient.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.AppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$2.run(AppClient.scala:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to change SPARK_MASTER_IP, SPARK_LOCAL_IP and many others config variables, but without success. Now I found some articles about submiting jars to Spark and I'm not sure (can't find any proof) if it is the cause? Are spark-submit and interactive shell the only ways to use spark?

Any articles about it? I would be grateful if you could give me a tip.

Comment: I am not sure if this answer your question directly, personally I generate a fat-jar using sbt assembly (the same thing should be possible with Maven), and I send it to the remote server (using scp for example) and I execute it there as any jar file.

Comment: Use `dse spark submit` it should pick up environmental variables for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would greatly recommend using `dse spark-submit` with dse. While it is not required it is definitely much easier than ensuring that your security and class path options as set up for DSE will work with your cluster. It also provides a much simpler approach (in my opinion) for configuring your SparkConf and placing jars on the executor class-paths.

Within DSE it also will automatically route your application to the correct Spark master url, further simplifying setup.

If you really want to manually construct your SparkConf be sure to map your spark master to the output of `dsetool spark-master` or it's equivalent in your version of DSE.

Comment: Thanks for response! I'm using http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/resources/DataStax-WP-Best_Practices_Running_DSE_Within_Docker.pdf and there is nothing about `dse spark-submit`. Let's say I don't need custom code (so no submit is required?) in spark on the beginning. Do you know if there is something more to do (more configuration?) to connect to spark?

Comment: Depending on what security and connection options you use it could be alot. For example if you use kerberos you need a custom authenticator from DSE build jar so that needs to be on the classpath and the correct hooks set. This also can change from version to version ...

Comment: I'm not using kerberos now. I just want get it working atm. It looks like it address ip which I can see in spark webUi. Its not public ip of my node( which I use to connect) but the internal docker network IP address... And none of variables settings can change that

Comment: DSE Spark by default binds the preferred ip of your C* node. This is the listen address unless you've set up your snitch to prefer an external ip (see Gossiping Property File Snitch or EC2Snitch).

You'll either need to map the connect address to the internal one, or change the way your spark connects.

Of course if you just run your application from inside the docker's network space you'll be fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a jar so that the executors can run your custom code. You can set this jar with `SparkConf.setJars`. But this is not a requirement for connecting to the Spark master and setting up a Spark application. Who knows, maybe you do not want to run any custom code. (This may reasonably be the case with Spark SQL.)

You also do not need to use `spark-submit`.

---

I don't know anything about DataStax, so it could be anything. But from the error message it looks like maybe your application is trying to connect to the wrong host, or there is a network issue. If you can reach the same Spark master from the same machine with `spark-shell`, then that's not the case of course. Check the master logs, maybe it can tell you why it is closing the connection from your application.